# How can you trigger a JS function when jumping within the same page?

Tags: javascript, anchor-scroll

I'm looking to make my page highlight the target location when an anchor href is followed.

At the moment it works fine when going to another page, but when I try to link to the same page, I'm unable to trigger the function. On a new page, it uses `$(document).ready` to call the function, but I don't know how to trigger it when it moves around the same page.

I have tried using onClick, but this causes a max stack issue and I'm hoping there's a better way to do it.

Is there a way to trigger on click with JQuery or Javascript?

EDIT:

My code was `onclick="highlightTarget()"`

which called

```
function highlightTarget () {
            //Get location
            var url = window.location.href;
            if(url.indexOf("#") != -1) {
                var anchor = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1);
                //Get element
                var element = document.getElementById(anchor);

                //Highlight if not null
                if(element != null)
                    highlightTarget(element)
            }
}
```

and the error I'd get is because this function would keep getting called and would fill the stack.

But I want to avoid using onClick because I would prefer to use a function so I wouldn't have to add onClick every time I made an anchor.

EDIT 2:

I found `.addEventListener("click", function() {` and that seems to be what I was looking for. Then I just added a class to each anchor as an identifier and found an array of elements with that class.

I'd delete this question but I'm hoping it can help somebody in the same situation if they can somehow find it. The existing answers didn't work for me.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: I said I've used onClick but I have no code for the JS trigger because I don't know how to do it.

It's posted above but I don't want to use it, so I don't know why you want it.

I'm wondering how it's possible to trigger JS when you jump within the same HTML page without using onClick.